MYSQL: Copy non NULL values from one table to another, WHERE row matches based on a column value
I hardly ever use MYSQL, but am having to use it for a small project.
I have two identical tables, both storing different data.
I want to be able to add data to Table A, and then if data exists in Table B that matches on a column value, then copy over any values that may exist into Table A and then remove that entry from Table B.
Example
Table B



NAME
AGE
HEIGHT
WEIGHT




BOB
2
10
10


TIM
NULL
20
20



Table A



NAME
AGE
HEIGHT
WEIGHT











Insert into TableA values ('TIM', 4, 10, NULL)

Table A



NAME
AGE
HEIGHT
WEIGHT




TIM
4
10
NULL



This should then check Table B for any entry that matches the NAME we just used and update Table A with any missing/wrong data, so that Table A ends up looking like this.
Table A



NAME
AGE
HEIGHT
WEIGHT




TIM
4
20
20



Then finally remove the entry from Table B
Table B



NAME
AGE
HEIGHT
WEIGHT




BOB
2
10
10



In the end Table A should have full updated records, and Table B should have anything that has not yet been correlated to something in Table A
I'm writing this as a stored procedure, and so I tried doing something like this:
INSERT INTO tableA (NAME, AGE, HEIGHT, WEIGHT) VALUES ( NAME_IN, AGE_IN, HEIGHT_IN, WEIGHT_IN);

SELECT * INTO @Aentry FROM tableA WHERE NAME = NAME_IN;

IF EXISTS ( SELECT * INTO @Bentry FROM tableB WHERE NAME = @Aentry.NAME)
THEN
UPDATE tableA SET
  NAME =IFNULL(@Bentry.NAME, NAME),
  AGE =IFNULL(@Bentry.AGE, AGE),
  HEIGHT =IFNULL(@Bentry.HEIGHT, HEIGHT),
  WEIGHT=IFNULL(@Bentry.WEIGHT, WEIGHT)
WHERE NAME = @Bentry.NAME;

DELETE FROM tableB WHERE NAME = @Aentry.NAME;
END IF;

But that doesn't seem to work due to the SELECT * it seems.

Are you needing a trigger, or just a separate piece of code you can include with your insert?

--  S a m p l e    D a t a :
/*   WITH TABLE_B
NAME    AGE HEIGHT  WEIGHT
------ ---- ------ ------- 
BOB       2     10      10
TIM    null     20      20    */

/*   WITH TABLE_A
NAME    AGE HEIGHT  WEIGHT
------ ---- ------ ------- 
TIM       4     10    null    */

UPDATE TABLE_A a
INNER JOIN TABLE_B b ON(b.NAME = a.NAME)
SET a.AGE = Case When Coalesce(a.AGE, 0) != b.AGE Then b.AGE Else a.AGE End,
    a.HEIGHT = Case When Coalesce(a.HEIGHT, 0) != b.HEIGHT Then b.HEIGHT Else a.HEIGHT End,
    a.WEIGHT = Case When Coalesce(a.WEIGHT, 0) != b.WEIGHT Then b.WEIGHT Else a.WEIGHT End;

/*    TABLE_A - after update
NAME    AGE HEIGHT  WEIGHT
------ ---- ------ ------- 
TIM       4     20      20    */

DELETE FROM TABLE_B b
WHERE EXISTS (Select 1 From TABLE_A a
              Where a.NAME = b.NAME And 
                    a.AGE Is Not Null And 
                    a.HEIGHT Is Not Null And 
                    a.WEIGHT Is Not Null);

/*    TABLE_B - after delete
NAME    AGE HEIGHT  WEIGHT
------ ---- ------ ------- 
BOB       2     10      10   */


An extra WHERE on the UPDATE might be wise, to avoid unnecessary updates.

@Charlieface You are right. It's just not quite clear to me what the real data look like. Just tried to show an option to do the update and delete. Not quite sure that with real data delete would work as expected. OP should know.  But, yes, unnecessary updates should be excluded with the where claise.
